# formatEther no longer works?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to convert bigNumber to Ether unit. I used the formatEther keyword but I keep getting "Typeerror: formatEther is not a function.

Here's the code:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");
const formatEther = require("ethers");

// copy-paste your URL provided in your Alchemy.com dashboard
const ALCHEMY_URL =
  "......";

axios
  .post(ALCHEMY_URL, {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "eth_getBalance",
    params: [
      "0xC..................", // Ethereum address
      "latest", // get latest account balance of the address
    ],
  })
  .then((response) => {
    const result = BigNumber(response.data.result);
    const numberString = formatEther(result);
    console.log(numberString);
  });
```

Comment: never share any API keys publicly on the internet. yours is included in your code snippet .. even if you just use it for testing or whatever, better keep secrets secret.

Comment: Hey, I see that documentation has changed, try destructuring formatEther. const {formatEther} = require('ethers');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below, you can use `ethers.utils.formatEther` and also `ethers.BigNumber.from` from [ethers utils](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/). This should do the job.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const ALCHEMY_URL = "YOUR_ALCHEMY_API_URL";

axios
  .post(ALCHEMY_URL, {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "eth_getBalance",
    params: [
      "0xC..................", // Ethereum address
      "latest", // get latest account balance of the address
    ],
  })
  .then((response) => {
    const result = ethers.BigNumber.from(response.data.result);
    const numberString = ethers.utils.formatEther(result);
    console.log(numberString);
  });
```

If you want to further destructure your imports you can do:

```
const { utils, BigNumber } = require("ethers");
```

and use it as follows:

```
const result = BigNumber.from(response.data.result);
const numberString = utils.formatEther(result);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined

Comment: what version of `ethers` are you using? check your `package.json`. The `cannot read ... from undefined` is an error couple of people have in beta version `ethers@6.x`, downgrade to `ethers@5.7.2` and reinstall packages, should work!

Comment: You're the best. It worked. I'd love to learn more from you - if you're open to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It still works, it's included in `utils`, check [here](https://0xf1C8535d1cAA6c17720FE1Bc0bd16092F8f8D62B)